# Selling stocks on a foreign exchange and converting proceeds to USD

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-exchange, currency

Let's say I had 100 shares of ABC on a foreign stock exchange. I sold the shares for a small profit in 2020 and received 1200 ₹. I'm a US resident, so I paid taxes on the gain in the US in 2021. Note that the proceeds were in a foreign currency, so in order to calculate my net gain in USD, I converted the amounts to USD using exchange rates at the time of each transaction:

| date sold | cost, ₹ | proceeds, ₹ | cost, USD | proceeds, USD | gain, USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 | 1000 | 1200 | 100 | 115 | 15 |

Next year, ie. in 2021, I sold my 1200 ₹ but received only 90 USD because the exchange rate was much worse than the rate I used previously to calculate my net gain. Would it be correct to report this transaction as a loss of 115-90=25 USD on my 2021 tax return?

Comment: I don't believe it would, unless you can somehow claim that the 1200 ₹ were held as investment. It doesn't sound so, it sounds like you just delayed the conversion and as the result got burned by the currency fluctuation.

Comment: @littleadv I held the 1200 ₹ for 6 mo. after I sold the shares. Why wouldn't it be a short-term investment?

Comment: Generally foreign currency is considered property, so in this case it's a personal property loss, not an investment loss.